# SQLite select query if inner join query doesn't exists

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables, one for all the foods which contains food id, default name and other foods values.

Another table is for the food name translations which contains food id, language id, translation.

What i want to do is join between these tables by the food id to get the translation for food id = 5 for example and language id = 1 which is Spanish for example. and i do it by:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Foods 
INNER JOIN FoodNameTranslations USING(Food_ID) 
WHERE Food_ID = 5 
AND Language_ID = 1
```

Now what if the the 'FoodNameTranslations' table doesn't have a translation for Food_ID 5 and Language 1?
then i want to simply get the food row with food id = 5 from the 'Foods' table (that contains the default name).

How can i make one query that does this? thanks!

Comment: You need an outer join: `SELECT * FROM Foods AS f LEFT JOIN FoodNameTranslations AS ft ON f.Food_ID = ft.Food_ID AND Language_ID = 1 WHERE Food_ID = 5`. Then apply `COALESCE` to get the best match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do a LEFT JOIN and put the language ID into the join condition.

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(t.TranslatedName, f.DefaultName) FoodName 
FROM 
    Foods f
    LEFT JOIN FoodNameTranslations t ON t.Food_ID = f.Food_ID AND t.Language_ID = 1
WHERE
    f.Food_ID = 5
```

Comment: This is amazing lol.. didn't know i could do it! now a quick quesition, if you wanted to get all the data from that row and on top of that also include the 'FoodName' column that the coalesce generated. i know i can write FoodName, calories, etc.. but is there a quicker way?

Comment: @Ofek Well now you do :)

Comment: @Ofek As a matter of fact, get used to the thought of always writing out all the columns you want to select. In a test query, you can do `SELECT *`, but in production use, spell out the columns you need. This has three advantages: **1)** It's much easier for the SQL engine to optimize the query when you only select what you need. **2)** It's less data to generate and transfer and therefore contributes to performance. **3)** It's much easier to use in a program when you don't keep scratching your head how the columns are called that a query selects, two weeks down the road.

Comment: But what if ill add a new column to the foods table then i might forget to change this query in the future. so wouldn't it be better to select all the columns from the foods table(excluding the defaultname if possible just so it wont be confusing) and also including the FoodName column we generated?

Comment: @Ofek You can mix and match freely `SELECT COALESCE(...) AS FoodName, f.Id AS FoodId, f.Calories, t.* FROM ...` - Just avoid the `*`  in production queries unless there are good reasons to use it.

Comment: ...actually there are four advantages, the fourth one being query stability: If your query uses `SELECT *` the result will change when you change the database layout, i.e. by adding a column to a table. With a fixed SELECT list, the query result stays the same, which means code using the query will not break as easily.

Comment: Well, yes i get what you are saying but if ill spell out the exact columns i need then when i change something the database then ill have to make sure that all the queries that the program uses are good for the new database layout, i just thought its better if it would be automatic but i guess ill have to change the code anyways in order to actually get the values from the query so it doesn't really matters :) thanks bro

Comment: @Ofek You have to do that anyway. When your program uses any column names and you change column names in the database, things will break whether or not you used `SELECT *`. For me, reasons 1 and 3 are the most important.

Answer (score 0):

You cando do this by changing the JOIN condition:

INNER JOIN gets all records that are common between both tables based on the supplied ON clause.

LEFT JOIN gets all records from the LEFT linked and the related record from the right table ,but if you have selected some columns from the RIGHT table, if there is no related records, these columns will contain NULL.

RIGHT JOIN is like the above but gets all records in the RIGHT table.

FULL JOIN gets all records from both tables and puts NULL in the columns where related records do not exist in the opposite table.

Try using LEFT JOIN instead INNER JOIN, you query will be like this:
SELECT * 
FROM Foods 
LEFT JOIN FoodNameTranslations USING(Food_ID) 
WHERE Food_ID = 5 
AND Language_ID = 1